# How can I display Image on the screen its not working I think I am failing to find a right path in img tag please guide me what should I do in it?

Tags: php, laravel

I have An issue in this code that I Couldn't find a right path to display image on screen please help me how to display image on screen? I think the problem is in my `<img>` tag

Image Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\ImageRequest;
use App\Models\Image;
use Validator;


class ImageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $images = Image::paginate(5);
       
       return view('admin.images.show-image', [
         'images' => $images
       ]);
    }

  

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
     public function store(Image $image,Request $request)
    {
         
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
         'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048',
         'product_id' => 'required'
 
        ]);
 
        $name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $product_id = $request->get('product_id');
        $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/images');
 
        $image = new Image;
 
        $image->name = $name;
        $image->product_id = $product_id;
        $image->path = $path;
        $image->save();
        return back()->with('status', 'Image Has been uploaded');
 
    }


     public function show()
    {
        return view('admin/images/upload');
    }


     public function edit(Image $image)
    {   
        return view('admin/images/edit-image',[
           'image' => $image
        ]);
    }


     public function update(Image $image ,Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'product_id' => 'required'
        ]);
        
        $image = Image::find($image->id);
        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $request->validate([
              'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            ]);
            $name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/images');
            $product_id = $request->get('product_id');
        }
        $image->name = $name;
        $image->product_id = $product_id;
        $image->path = $path;
        $image->save();
    
        return back()->with('success','Image updated successfully');
 
    }



    public function destroy(Image $image)
    {
        $image = Image::find($image->id);
        if ($image->delete()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

show-image.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('title', 'Industries')
@section('content')

 <div class="container-fluid">

          <!-- Page Heading -->
          <h1 class="h3 mb-2 text-gray-800">Admin Dashboard</h1><br>

      <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Industries</h1>
        <a href="{{url('admin/images/upload')}}" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm">
            <i class="fas fa-download fa-sm text-white-50"></i> 
            Upload Images
        </a>
    </div>

          <!-- DataTales Example -->
          <div class="card shadow mb-4">
            <div class="card-header py-3">
              <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Image Table</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                         {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                         @endif
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Sr</th>
                      <th>Product</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Image</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    @foreach($images as $image)
                    <tr id="row-{{$image->id}}">
                      <td>{{ $image->id }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $image->product->name }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $image->name }}</td>
                      <td>
                        <img src="{{url('public/images'.$image->name)}}" style="width: 250px; height: 150px">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        
                        <a href="{{ url('admin/images/'.$image->id. '/edit' )}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>

                       <a href="" data-id="{{$image->id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-del">Delete</a>
                        
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    @endforeach
                  </tbody>

                </table>
               {{ $images->links() }}
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
@endsection

@section('page_specific_js')

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-del").click(function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      if(confirm("Really mean to delete this record.")) {
        $.post("{{url('admin/images')}}/"+id,
        {
          _token: "{{csrf_token()}}",
          _method: "DELETE"
        },
        function(data){
          if(data) {
            $('#row-'+id).remove();
          } else {
            alert("There is some problem, Please try again later.");
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add a slash in below code and than check also make sure your image name saved in DB and and image in public/images folder

```
<img src="{{url('public/images/'.$image->name)}}" style="width: 250px; height: 150px">
```

Comment: where I need to add slash? and in db the name is showing

Comment: please update below line of code with your code in show-image.blade.php file 

<img src="{{url('public/images/'.$image->name)}}" style="width: 250px; height: 150px">